# Error: Module administration/tfasettings not found

Tags: cumulocity

I'm busy working on developing some plugins and apps, and when i am running c8y server locally and i try to enter Administration, i keep getting the following error:

> Error: Module administration/tfasettings not found

Any ideas?

Comment: what  version are you using?

Comment: If i run c8y -V, it returns 2.1.3

Comment: Sorry, I think @confraria meant the version of the SDK, not the one of the c8y tool. That defines what modules are included. Check the "version" property in node_modules/cumulocity-ui-build/package.json in your project. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.

Version 9.1.0

Comment: Ah, I found the issue, let me find a workaround.

Comment: Hey Andre, 

Any luck in finding a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

We have already fixed the issue for versions *>= 9.1.0*. Please try to install version *9.1.0* (or higher) with `c8y install` command. If administration/tfasettings
is still missing use `npm cache clean --force` and then once again try to install version 9.1.0 (or higher) with `c8y install` command.

Best regards

Dawid